# Graph theory : meaning of "bottleneck"

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hall's theorem states: Let G be a bipartite graph with vertex partition L;R. There is matching in G that covers L iff no subset of L is a bottleneck.
what is the meaning of bottleneck?

Comment: Has less neighbors than elements.

Comment: Maybe you have to review it on your textbook...

Comment: Thank you @Berci

Answer (score 0):

A set S is called **bottleneck** if
|S| > |N(S)|, where N(S) is the neighbors of S.
(a vertex v is said to be neighbor to u if (v, u) is an edge in the graph).

In other words, a set S is **bottleneck** if it has elements more than neighbors (as Berci commented.)